# searchBarSearchButtonClicked not working Swift

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

Iam trying to use UISearchBar but it's not working with me

here's my code

```
class searchViewController: UIViewController  , UITableViewDataSource , UISearchBarDelegate{
    var searchResults = [String]()
    @IBOutlet weak var searchTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mySearchBar: UISearchBar!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return searchResults.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = searchTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("searchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell


        return cell
    }
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print("print anything ")
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print(self.mySearchBar.text)
    }



}
```

when i click in the search button in the keyboard using simulator no thing is happen

i tried **searchBarTextDidBeginEditing**  it's not working too

did i do something wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is fine, but you need to set `mySearchBar.delegate = self` or you could do it on the storyboard, using ctrl+drag the search bar to the viewController and choosing delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, just include UISearchBarDelegate with UIViewController issue resolved.